# Recycler View in Android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am retrieving data from firebase into my android application.
The data is fetching correctly.
The data is added one below the other but I want that as the new data is added, it should be displayed at the top of the view rather than at the bottom.
Please help

any method in java file or any attribute in xml file

Comment: are you using firestore or realtime database

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: Are you asking how to [show data in descending order])https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bandroid%5D+descending)?

Comment: Just add it to index of (0)

Comment: If you fetch the whole list , please sort it by your property.